# Prevent Zoom Picture-in-picture adjusted size and location from resetting

Tags: macos, catalina, accessibility, zoom

I use the zoom part of the accessability features of OSX, in Picture-in-picture mode. I like having a certain size zoom window at the center of the screen, and I know how to do that and adjust the zoom to my liking, but after I reset the computer, these settings are reset.

Is there a way to persist them ?

I don't mind writing a script for this, if you can point me in the right direction.

Comment: "after I reset the computer" you mean restart? Also, Use this answer to get yourself started, in case there is no easy solution.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542826/applescript-editor-record-doesnt-work/18752770#18752770 then you can use answers on this site to launch this script at startup. or you can use this menu item:https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/373375/how-to-run-an-applescript-when-safari-starts-up, or you can bind it to a Finder or all apps' shortcut: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/175215/how-do-i-assign-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-an-applescript-i-wrote

Comment: After looking around a bit, I'm pretty sure the settings that control the window size are in this file : ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.universalaccess.plist , so I need to confirm, and then maybe write something as simple as copying a file at startup, or at most just modifying a particular property if I want to get fancy.

Comment: You can compare the plist files: **1** when your desired room factor is active, **2** after restart. If there's a difference, you can indeed write a script to change that.